# Node JS on singe vCPU vs multi vCPU

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vcpu

We are in the process of setting up our production Node JS application in AWS, and trying to choose between single vCPU EC2 instance vs multi vCPU EC2 instance. What are things we should consider, please share your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach would be to find out how NODE.JS requirement. If it can fit well in single vCPU i.e. t2.micro or t2.nano then go ahead with that.

Mean while AWS offers you EC2 interface from which you can change type of instance any time to intances with more number of vCPU. So, there is no worry you can easily change by

1. Select the instanc in EC2
2. Stop the instance
3. change type
4. select more advance type like t2.large or higher

EC2 is very flexible architecture. Having said that always keep your eye on your bill

Comment: Thanks Mohtisham, It makes sense! Also, I got a chance to connect with AWS SA's just today and received similar feedback